# Bootstrap button loading + Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's button loading state (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons).

```
HTML:

<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Register" id="accountRegister" data-loading-text="Loading..."/>

JS:

(function ($, undefined) {
    $("#accountRegister").click(function () {
        $(this).button('loading');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/?/register/",
            data:$("#loginForm").serialize(),
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#accountRegister").button('reset');
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#accountRegister").button('reset');
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
})(jQuery);
```

But if I have many buttons I need to write many functions (?).
Of course I can make something like this:

```
$(".ajax-button").bind("click", function() { 
     $(this).button("loading");})
```

And I can use jQuery Ajax event `ajaxComplete`

```
$(".ajax-button").bind("ajaxComplete", function() { 
     $(this).button("reset");})
```

But this way **ALL** buttons will be set to normal state when **any** Ajax request completed.

If user will click on *button1* and then click on *button2* (both buttons are sending Ajax request), they will be set to normal state when first Ajax request is completed. How to determine which button I need to set to a normal state?

Thank you in advance.

### UPDATE

All I need is determine which button triggered some action (Ajax request), set it state to *loading* and when Ajax request will be completed set it state to normal.

Comment: Do the buttons have common functionality?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes, they both send ajax requests.

Comment: yes, but are they the same request? Do they both serialize the login form?

Comment: @Jeemusu no, they can send different requests, include GET and POST with different paths. Login form just for illustrate the current code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found solution for my question =)
After reading jQuery documentation I wrote this code for my system:

**core.js:**

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend:function (xhr, settings) {
            if (settings.context != undefined && settings.context.hasClass('btn')) {
                settings.context.button('loading');
            }
        },
        complete:function () {
            this.button('reset');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**account.js:**

```
(function ($, undefined) {
    $("#accountRegister").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            context:$(this), // You need to set context to 'this' element
            //some code here
        });
        return false;
    })
})(jQuery);
```

This works perfectly.
Hope that this will be useful for someone.

Comment: could you explain what exactly these two calls do:
`settings.context.button('loading')` and `this.button('reset')`. When I run this with jQuery and Bootstrap and debug `settings.context.button` it returns some sort of Bootstrap object.