# ASP.net MVC5 submit loading state

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change button text to loading as in bootstrap without post to ajax by using bootstrap data-loading-text="Loading..."

In the below example , want to show loading when user clicks and after response has to reset to normal

```
 <button type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..."  value="Log in"
   class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-1">
                                   <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                                   <span>Sign in</span>
                               </button>
```

Comment: But there wont be a response if an ajax request isn't made, could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: Check this link might be helpful http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=stateful-button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap button loading + Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197537/bootstrap-button-loading-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
core.js:

(function ($, undefined) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend:function (xhr, settings) {
            if (settings.context != undefined && settings.context.hasClass('btn')) {
                settings.context.button('loading');
            }
        },
        complete:function () {
            this.button('reset');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
account.js:

(function ($, undefined) {
    $("#accountRegister").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            context:$(this), // You need to set context to 'this' element
            //some code here
        });
        return false;
    })
})(jQuery);
```